# INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND when running ASP.NET WebAPI application in Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Running the Web API application based on OData inside the Docker.
`docker run -d --name myApp -p 5000:80 sample`
the Docker file is like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

EXPOSE 5000

EXPOSE 453

USER ContainerAdministrator

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY /Service ./
```

Service includes the bin and Web.config.

Trying to access http://localhost:500 in the browser (Chrom, Edge, and Internet explorer the same).
Receiving the following error:

*There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND*

Answer (score 0):

This error should be network configuration errors causing name resolution maflunctions, you can try following methods to slove this question.

1. Disable "TCP Fast Open" feature in Microsoft Edge. Locate the
   "Networking" section and uncheck the "Enable TCP Fast Open" box
   before restarting Edge in order to apply the change.
2. Change DNS server.
3. DNS Flush. open the command prompt by pressing the Windows home button, type “cmd” in the search window, and then press the Enter key. Then enter the following command: `ipconfig /flushdns`
4. Reset network settings with netsh. Enter the following command into the open command line to reset the TCP/IP stack to factory settings: `netsh int ip reset`. Afterwards, it is recommended to also reset the catalog of the Windows programming interface, Winsock (Windows Sockets). Windows automatically creates entries for successfully established network connections, which may also lead to network problems. The required command line command is: `netsh winsock reset catalog`
5. Change user account control settings. open the control panel and select the "User Accounts" area. click again on “User Accounts” and then on “Change User Account Control settings.” In the final step, move the slider up to allow Windows notifications.

For more methods and detailed steps, you can refer to this link: [INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/inet-e-resource-not-found-error/).